# How do I get a list of default values for all parameters of a report?

Tags: sql, vb.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report and I want to get the default values for each parameter ***before the user hits "View Report"***. The tricky part is that some parameters could be generated from a query.

For example, if the user opens this report, they see these values as the defaults:

[image]

(the image above is a screenshot of what the user sees before they change any of the parameters and before the hit "View report")

Each of the multi-valued parameters are being generated either from a query or from a stored procedure. I need to get the values that get generated for these. The overall goal behind all this is that I will then use these to figure out which parameters the user *changed* when they ran the report.

So take a look at the `Commodity` parameter. There are a lot of default values for it. Let's say that the user only selected "Bags". I would need to use either VB code or SQL to figure out that the user changed the default value of that parameter from all of the results returned from that query to only "Bags". How do I do this?

Comment: Whoever downvoted - can I get an explanation as to why you did that? I can modify the question if something about it bothered you.

Comment: You provided a picture and no data.  Please provide all relevant data, queries, and expected results in table form.

Comment: You should also include all relevant code and any attempts made to solve the problem

Comment: @DanielMarcus I think you should read the question more carefully. I have already provided all relevant information. There is no reason to provide the select statement that generates the parameter values and I certainly do not need to show the results in table form because this is a standard method of using a query to generate the possible values for a report parameter. Moreover, the focus of this question is on *creating* a way to do something, not fixing a problem.

Comment: @AFriend please see previous comment. Besides this, I have made numerous attempts to find a way to do this. I did not document where I got stuck in each attempt. I could eventually list all of the attempts I made, but for starters I was hoping to find someone who has already done what I am trying to do and can provide the method quickly.

Comment: If you had done that then the question would be much higher quality, and a little effort shows that you've actually tried.

Comment: Your only option is going to be to read the value of the field when it gets set and the read the value of the field when the user hits "View Report". I know you want to get the values before they hit view report, but you could do the processing that needs to be done during the click event of view report and then go from there. Otherwise you would have to add a listener to each field and check for when the text was changed in each field and record the change.

Comment: Try adding clones of these parameters as hidden and assign the same or clones of the dataset's that return the default values

Answer (score 2):

You can make clones of the parameters and use the same dataset's (you may have to make clones of the datasets in case you are using cascading parameters)

In my example, initially both parameters get the first year from the dataset which is 2003.
After the user makes a selection, the original parameter value (which will be set as internal - I 've left it visible for the example) retains the initial value of the dataset, while the user parameter returns the selected year.

[image]

Comment: This would be my approach, simple to do and nothing outside standard SSRS/SQL to compare and store the results.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does support cascading parameters. This all happens before you View the report. So the datasets that run to get subsequent parameter Available Values, can refer to the values of previous parameters. However, this only goes one way. You can't check the value of the next parameter because it doesn't exist in that scope.

As a general rule, this behavior is not intended to be used for other purposes. But I suppose there's nothing stopping you from calling a stored procedure on your last parameter query and performing some operations right before they run the report.

I don't have the full picture of what you're trying to accomplish, but I hope this at least points you in the right direction.